# Java - notify() vs notifyAll() - possible deadlock?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there any situation in which `notify()` can cause deadlock, but `notifyAll()` - never?

For example, in case of multiple locks. `notify()` notifies only one thread to run, which checks for lock to some object and becomes waiting again, though another thread could unlock that object. In case of using `notifyAll()`, all threads will be notified to run and one of them in its turn will unlock that object for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Imagine you implement the Producer - Consumer problem with `synchronize, wait, and notify`. **(edit)** In which 2 Producers and 2 Consumers all wait on the same object monitor **(end edit)**.The Producer calls `notify` in this implementation. Now suppose you have two Threads running the Producer's code path. It is possible that Producer1 calls `notify` and wakes Producer2. Producer2 realizes he can not do any work and subsequently fails to call `notify`. Now you are deadlocked.

**(edit)** Had `notifyAll` been called, then both Consumer1 and Consumer2 would have woken up in addition to Producer2. One of the Consumers would have consumed the data and in turn called `notifyAll` to wake up at least one Producer, thus allowing the very broken implementation to limp along successfully.

Here is the reference question I base my scenario off of:
[My Produce Consumer Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067877/my-produce-consumer-hangs)

Comment: Why would Producer2 be waiting on the object that Producer1 notifies?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Oh, that's odd, everybody just waits on the queue in your "reference question."  That's a broken producer/consumer example then I'd say...typically you have a "empty" monitor and a "full" monitor; producers wait on the full monitor and notify the empty monitor, consumers wait on the empty monitor and notify the full monitor.  But you did succeed in giving an example.

Comment: @Mark Peters, yes well, nobody said anything about the code being of any type of quality. I assume whatever code inspired such a generic question from the OP is easily as confused/confusing as the code from my reference question.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Imagine you have three Consumer, but only one can do some actual work at the given point. If you use `notifyAll` at that point the Consumer that actually can do some work might starve since it is possible that the other two might pass the lock between each other.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson, actually, no. Principally because the Consumers which could not do work would in fact not call `notify()` or `notifyAll()` and thus not be capable of awakening each other. Remember, in the old school wait/notify paradigm, notify is only ever called for the purposes of telling someone "Hey I DID something related to this, you might want to check it out."

Comment: Probably the question should have been "Is there any _sensible_ situation which would deadlock…". That said, strictly speaking this is not a deadlock situation, since there is only one lock involved, it cannot be deadlocked… This is actually more of a resource starvation.